# Linq to Entity Query .Expand

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services

I got the following tables 
`TableA`, `TableB`, `TableC`, `TableD`, `TableE` and they have foreign key relations like 
FK_AB(one to many),FK_BC(one to one),FK_CD(One to many),FK_DE(one to one) and have the navigation properties based on these foreignkeys
Now I want to query TableA and get the records from TableA, TableD and TableE whoose Loadedby column equal to System. My query is like below

```
var query= from A in Context.TableA.Expand(TableB/TableC/TableD).Expand(TableB/TableC/TableD/TableE)
           where A.Loadedby=="System"
           select A;
```

The above query is working fine. I want the records from TableD and TableE whoose Loadedby value equal to System but the above query returning all the records from TableD and TableE which are related to TableA record satisfying A.Loadedby="System" this condition is not checked in the child tables.

Can anyone tell me how to filter the child tables also.

Comment: A.LoadedBy only applies to the TableA, what would it mean for TableB (which probably doesn't even have LoadedBy property and even if it does, it might be of a different type and so on).

Comment: There is LoadedBy property with same type in TableB also. I want to filter TableD and TableE with LoadedBy property and these tables also has this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently OData only supports filters on the top-level. So in the above example it can only filter rows from the TableA. Inside expansions all the approriate rows will be included, always, there's no way to filter those right now.
You might be able to ask for the exanded entities separately with additional queries (with the right filter) and possibly use batch to group all the queries in one request. But that depends on the actual query you need to send.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Based on the result of the first query(parent entity rows) we will be quering child tables. So in this case can we use batch

Comment: If the comment was a question: If you need the result of the first query in order to issue a second query, then you can't use batch.