# WCF Data Services join query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services

I want to retrieve the results of this query (Northwind Database):

```
var ent = new Entities();

var query = from c in ent.Customers
    join o in ent.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
    join od in ent.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
    join p in ent.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
    where p.ProductName == "Chai"
    select c;
```

by using WCF Data Services. I type this (which doesn't work):

```
http://localhost:29792/WcfDataService1.svc/Customers?$select=CompanyName&$expand=Orders/Order_Details/Products?$filter='Name' eq 'Chai'
```

How should I type it correctly?

Comment: As it seems, when I create a separate project and add a service reference, when I try to execute this command I get a "NotSupportedException - The method 'Join' is not supported."

Comment: Yes it's one of the many [Unsupported LINQ Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx) in WCF DS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418745/linq-to-entity-query-expand

Answer (score 0):

Although `Join` isn't supported, navigation properties/associations are, and you can also use `.Expand()`. So although you can't get it from `.Join`, there are multiple ways to get the data you need.

Comment: Any suggestions on this particular case? You mean I can get all results and then filter them afterwards?

Comment: I would use LINQ projections if you want to select, or Expand if you want to update. No, the filtering is done in the WCF service.